# Prove that each tree has at most one perfect matching

Tags: graph-theory

I need help with the following proof:

> Prove that each tree has at most one perfect matching.

We know that: perfect matching = covers each vertex just once.

So the proof itself I tried to prove by controversy:

- the so-called I assume that some tree has two perfect matchings.
- Let there be perfect matchings on the tree $T = (V,E)$ (let's call these matchings $M$, $M'$)
- Next, consider a graph on vertices from the set $V$ (so-called all vertices of the tree $T$), which are also vertices $M\cup M'$
- If, but $M$ and $M'$ are perfect matchings (so-called cover all vertices), then each element of this new graph is either a vertex that belongs to $M$, $M'$ or a cycle.
- But $T = (V, E)$ is a tree and cannot contain a cycle (Dispute) $\Rightarrow\ M = M'$.

And here I assumed that the claim was proved, but during the follow-up check I was criticized for the following:

- the vertices located in $M\cup M'$ are all vertices of the tree (It probably made sense to consider all edges of $M\cup M'$)… in this case, however, the components will be only paths (The cycle by definition cannot be, because $T = (V, E)$ is a tree)… so if we have paths, what next? (Dispute is not visible!)

Couldn't anyone please advise me how to reformulate this proof correctly, or if it can be done differently and better? Thank you for any advice.

Comment: I would solve it by mathematical induction on the number of edges. Not by contradiction.

Comment: It perhaps simpler to consider the subgraph $(V,M\Delta M')$ where $M\Delta M' = (M\setminus M')\cup(M'\setminus M)$. Possible degrees in this subgraph are 0,1,2.  But if both $M'$ and $M'$ are perfect, only 0 or 2 are possible. But inside a tree, 2 is impossible.

Answer (score 1):

Your reasoning is difficult to understand, but the idea is correct. It seems to me that the reasoning could be as follows. I'll tell you very briefly:

In fact, let for some tree $T$ there exist two perfect matchings $M$ and $M'$ and let an edge $e\in M$, but $e\notin M'$. Let $e=x_1x_2$. Since $M'$ is a perfect matching, then there exists an edge $e'\in M'$ and $e'=x_2x_3$.

We have $x_1x_2x_3$ is a path in which the edges from $M$ and $M'$ alternate: $x_1x_2\in M$, $x_2x_3\in M'$.

Now we choose a path of maximal length in the tree $T$, in which the edges of $M$ and $M'$ alternate. Let it be $x_1x_2,\ldots,x_s$ and $x_1x_2\in M$. Since $M'$ is a perfect matching there exists an edge $x_1x_0\in M'$ and $x_0\neq x_i$, since $T$ has no cycles. This, however, contradicts the maximality of the chosen path.